# Spacy-Transformers: Access GPT-2?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, spacy, gpt-2

I'm using Spacy-Transformers to build some NLP models.

The [Spacy-Transformers docs](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-transformers#gatsby-noscript) say:

> **spacy-transformers**
>
> *spaCy pipelines for pretrained BERT, XLNet and GPT-2*

The sample code on that page shows:

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_trf")
doc = nlp("Apple shares rose on the news. Apple pie is delicious.")
```

Based on what I've learned from [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vyOgWhwUmec),"en_core_web_trf" appears to be the `spacy.load()` package to use a BERT model. I've searched the [Spacy-Transformers docs](https://spacy.io/universe/project/spacy-transformers#gatsby-noscript) and haven't yet seen an equivalent package, to access GPT-2. Is there a specific `spacy.load()` package, to load in order to use a GPT-2 model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `en_core_web_trf` uses a specific Transformers model, but you can specify arbitrary ones using the `TransformerModel` wrapper class from `spacy-transformers`. See [the docs](https://spacy.io/api/architectures#TransformerModel) for that. An example config:

```
[model]
@architectures = "spacy-transformers.TransformerModel.v1"
name = "roberta-base" # this can be the name of any hub model
tokenizer_config = {"use_fast": true}
```

Comment: Could you please post a link to the list of available models? I found this, but it doesn't seem to include GPT-2, or roberta-base:  https://huggingface.co/transformers/search.html?q=roberta-base&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: Model names come from here. Not sure how to filter for the compatible ones, but it's a lot of them. https://huggingface.co/models